# Can anyone identify as to the scripture in which Sri Sankara stated sloka?

Tags: identification-request, adi-shankaracharya, ramana-maharshi

The following is from **Letters from Sri Ramanasramam**.

Sri Ramana Maharshi quoted therein a sloka from Sri Adi Sankara.

[image]

Can anyone identify as to the scripture in which Sri Sankara stated so?

Comment: This is from Sankara's  "Nirguna Manasa Puja", Ramanaji's quote is verse 26.

Comment: Please post the answer giving details

Comment: Not sure what more 'details' you need. I have given the writing of Sankara it comes from, and the exact verse number. Ramama Maharishi has quoted the verse exactly.

Comment: You can post an answer.  That is what I am asking for